Need help using multiple navigators in Flutter web
I am trying to maintain a persistent sidebar, a custom widget, and then keeping a tab on the selected page by using the index of the type of int. The problem is the sidebar elements. I have no issues showing them using IndexedStack but want to navigate inside those children in IndexedStack deeply.
class AppLayout extends StatefulWidget {
  const AppLayout({super.key});

  @override
  AppLayoutState createState() => AppLayoutState();
}

class AppLayoutState extends State<AppLayout> {
  int selected = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 300,
            color: Colors.indigo,
            child: LeftPane(
              selected: selected,
              mainNavAction: (index) {
                setState(() {
                  selected = index;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: IndexedStack(
              index: selected,
              children: [
                Navigator(
                  initialRoute: '/',
                  onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
                    switch (settings.name) {
                      case '/':
                        return CustomPageRoute(page: const CategoriesView());
                    }

                    return null;
                  },
                  onUnknownRoute: (settings) {
                    return MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => const ErrorRoute(),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                Navigator(
                  initialRoute: '/',
                  onGenerateRoute: (settings) {
                    switch (settings.name) {
                      case '/':
                        return CustomPageRoute(page: const ProfessionsView());
                      case ProfessionDetailsView.route:
                        final args = settings.arguments as Profession;
                        return CustomPageRoute(
                          page: ProfessionDetailsView(profession: args),
                        );
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onUnknownRoute: (settings) {
                    return MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => const ErrorRoute(),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

My question is if its the right way of doing this? Furthermore, The CustomRoute is used for no transitions.
class CustomPageRoute extends PageRouteBuilder {
  final Widget page;

  CustomPageRoute({required this.page})
      : super(
          pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => page,
          transitionDuration: Duration.zero,
          reverseTransitionDuration: Duration.zero,
        );
}


You can try: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_split_view
